# Correlation and causation ID in Commanded

Tags: events, elixir, cqrs, event-sourcing, commanded

Greg Young, author of [Event Store](https://eventstore.org/), [defined a while ago](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/event-store/pvk2iEBgBtA/vvjxQZEiYK4J) the correlation ID to reference the root cause and the causation ID to reference the direct cause of a message.

Therefore you should be able to find the one message to which another message is a direct response through the other message's causation ID. And you should be able to find all messages within the same conversation by them having the same causation ID.

If this pattern is applied, the second message in a conversation should have both the correlation ID and the causation ID set to the first message.

In Commanded, I would have expected the first event to have both correlation ID and causation ID to point to the command which caused the event to occur (also visually described [here](https://railseventstore.org/docs/correlation_causation/)).

Confusingly in Commanded's own event store, it seems, that the first event after a command has differing correlation and causation IDs. So it seems Commanded doesn't apply Greg Young's definition.

My question would be, what exactly is the definition for these IDs in Commanded? Was it a conscious decision not to follow Greg Young's definition, and if so, why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Commanded has implemented [correlation and causation ids](https://github.com/commanded/commanded/blob/master/guides/Commands.md#correlation-and-causation-ids) as described in the guides, copied below.

By default commands *will not* be persisted, therefore you cannot follow the chain of cause and affect from command > event > command unless you also persist incoming commands. You can use [Commanded audit middleware](https://github.com/commanded/commanded-audit-middleware) to store dispatched commands to any Ecto supported database. Doing so will allow you to tie commands and their resultant events together. The correlation id can also be used to associated all related messages, assuming you are copying them when dispatching commands. There's an example of doing so given below.

In Greg's Event Store I think the causation id is copied from event to event, ignoring the intermediate command, since his event store is only storing the events.

---

#### Correlation and causation ids

To assist with monitoring and debugging your deployed application it is useful to track the causation and correlation ids for your commands and events.

- `causation_id` - the UUID of the command causing an event, or the event causing a command dispatch.
- `correlation_id` - a UUID used to correlate related commands/events.

You can set causation and correlation ids when dispatching a command:

```
:ok = ExampleRouter.dispatch(command, causation_id: UUID.uuid4(), correlation_id: UUID.uuid4())
```

When dispatching a command in an event handler, you should copy these values from the event your are processing:

```
defmodule ExampleHandler do
  use Commanded.Event.Handler, name: "ExampleHandler"

  def handle(%AnEvent{..}, metadata) do
    %{event_id: causation_id, correlation_id: correlation_id} = metadata

    ExampleRouter.dispatch(%ExampleCommand{..},
      causation_id: causation_id,
      correlation_id: correlation_id
    )
  end
end
```

Commands dispatched by a process manager will be automatically assigned the appropriate causation and correlation ids from the source domain event.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications. But I still wonder why on the first event, correlation and causation aren't the same.

Does that mean the correlation ID is just a random value and neither the ID of a command or an event?

Comment: The correlation id is used to associate related messages (commands & events). It will be set to a random UUID if you don't provide it during command dispatch. As an example, you could decide to use an application specific correlation id (such as `order_id` or `reservation_id`) to help associate related messages together in an easily identifiable way.

Whereas the causation id is the identity of the previous message allowing you to follow a chain of messages over time. It will be unset (`nil`) for any command that is not triggered as a reaction to an event.

Comment: Sadly, the correlation ID always needs to be a UUID. Therefore it is often impossible to set it to something relevant for the business. See https://github.com/commanded/commanded/issues/233